# Twitter embedd not rendering react native render html

Tags: android, react-native, webview, react-native-render-html

I am using react-native-render-html@foundry

```
          <HTML
           contentWidth={Dimensions.get('screen').width}
           onLinkPress={(e,href)=>onShouldStartLoadWithRequest(e,href)}
           html={item.news.content.rendered}
           tagsStyles={ { p: { textAlign:'justify', fontSize:18, fontStyle: 'normal', color: !context.state.color?customcolor.black: customcolor.white ,fontFamily:customfonts.font} }}
           WebView={WebView}
           />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a custom renderer for `iframe` tags. Fortunately, there is a plugin just for that: [`@native-html/iframe-plugin`](https://github.com/native-html/plugins/tree/master/packages/iframe-plugin#readme)